# Search two different string patterns in one line

Tags: powershell

**THE SCENARIO**

I have a *.txt file containing 3 lines:

```
test-1234.htm
test-5678.htm
somefile.htm
```

I need a script which will find specific string patterns in that *.txt file.

Currently, following script will find all *.htm files in *.txt file and store results in specified results.log file.

```
dir *.txt | Select-String -pattern "\.htm$" |Select-Object -Expandproperty line | Out-File results.log -Encoding utf8 -Width 500
```

**QUESTION**

How to modify it, so it only finds all "test-****.htm" lines?

(Will only log lines containing "test-" and ".htm")

Comment: Just change your regex to `^test.+\.htm$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the hints!

Ultimately I got it working with:

```
test-.{4,}\.htm$
```

This way I was able to also include in results lines with digits+characters (for example "*test-a12c.htm*") and lines where there was something before the key word "test" (for example "this is a *test-13bg.htm*".

@ user1432893

The site you've provided helped me with this! THX!

@ Dave Sexton

with ^ in argument it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the pattern argument to `test-\d*.htm`

'\d' - "Matches any digit character (0-9)"

'*' - "Match or more of the preceding token"

so it will match any num of digits

if you want to match at least 4 digits you can use `test-\d{4,}.htm`

i would recommend playing with regex using this site: http://regexr.com/